# SPFX customFormatter

Tags: spfx-webparts, json-formatting

Is it possible to take the JSON of a customFormatter from a field info object and apply it when rendering a component?
I would like to render choice fields as they are displayed in a list view.
For example, the choice field has this CustomFormatter:

```
CustomFormatter : "{\"elmType\":\"div\",\"style\":{\"flex-wrap\":\"wrap\",\"display\":\"flex\"},\"children\":[{\"elmType\":\"div\",\"style\":{\"box-sizing\":\"border-box\",\"padding\":\"4px 8px 5px 8px\",\"overflow\":\"hidden\",\"text-overflow\":\"ellipsis\",\"display\":\"flex\",\"border-radius\":\"16px\",\"height\":\"24px\",\"align-items\":\"center\",\"white-space\":\"nowrap\",\"margin\":\"4px 4px 4px 4px\"},\"attributes\":{\"class\":{\"operator\":\":\",\"operands\":[{\"operator\":\"==\",\"operands\":[\"@currentField\",\"Choice 1\"]},\"sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCornflowerBlue sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-CornflowerBlueFont\",{\"operator\":\":\",\"operands\":[{\"operator\":\"==\",\"operands\":[\"@currentField\",\"Choice 2\"]},\"sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont\",{\"operator\":\":\",\"operands\":[{\"operator\":\"==\",\"operands\":[\"@currentField\",\"Choice 3\"]},\"sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GoldFont\",{\"operator\":\":\",\"operands\":[{\"operator\":\"==\",\"operands\":[\"@currentField\",\"\"]},\"\",\"sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary\"]}]}]}]}},\"txtContent\":\"@currentField\"}],\"templateId\":\"BgColorChoicePill\"}"
```

which is accessible simply doing

```
const formatter = JSON.parse(props.customFormatter)
```

now the next step is to apply the logic of the formatter to the choices, is that even possible?

```
Choices: Array(3)
0: "Choice 1"
1: "Choice 2"
2: "Choice 3"
```

Comment: I think you will have to re-create CSS styling in your SPFx code.

Comment: Unless there is a solution I will just display the choice options as "grey pills". I'm thinking either there someone made an easy solution for it or it's gonna be super, not-worth-the-effort hard to do this